# Menu based on SqlSiteMapProvider needs refresh

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sitemap

In ASP .Net 4.0 Web Forms 'Site' project: I have a Menu on a master page that is populated with SqlSiteMapProvider. It works, but sometimes requires a manual browser refresh to actually appear on screen.

Page Markup:

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapSource" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu"  runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapSource" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"     IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
</asp:Menu>                
</div>
```

I know the connection and configuration is correct because after hitting refresh everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust  `EnableViewState="true"` in order to persist without Bind every Load or Post.

Try with

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapSource" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu"  runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapSource" 
    CssClass="menu" 

EnableViewState="true"     

    IncludeStyleBlock="false" 
    Orientation="Horizontal">
</asp:Menu>                
</div>
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic5

Comment: Great. that seemed to work. I re-ran the project a handful of times from Visual Studio and the menu came up every time. Thanks.

Comment: I'am happy to help you user1022133